# How to integrate AngularJs with Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I have little/no knowdlege in AngularJs, i want to create a very simple SPA with django as backend and AngularJs as frontend. User will be able to Register, Login & logout all taking place on the same page when a user logs in they will see a message"Welcome (user email)".

This is very easy to do in a normal django web app as we don't even need to create the whole authentication system. But i want to learn how to do this with AngularJS as my employer wants me to do.

I have read the basics of AngularJs and it looked well explained (it made sense) but how to integrate it with django. I tried searching on the internet but there is nothing out there, the tutorials that are there are more then 7 years old.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to look at angular HttpClient because that what going to enable communication between django and angular..then create a service to handle authentication you can call it anything import HttpClient inside to login user for example i will do this:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  // Skip authorization from these requests
  private skip_token_headers = {
    skip: "true"
  };
  loginUser(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.makePostRequest(environment.LOGIN_URL, user, 
    this.skip_token_headers);
  }
  makePostRequest(url: string, data: any, req_headers: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: req_headers });
  }
```

then in your login component under .ts you import your service and use it like bellow

```js
onLoginSuccess(result){
    localStorage.setItem('token', result.key);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result.user));       
    
    this.router.navigate(['/userpage']);
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.authService.loginUser(this.user).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.onLoginSuccess(result);
      },
      error => {
        this.login_errors = [];
        if (error['error']['non_field_errors']) {
          this.login_errors = error['error']['non_field_errors'];
        }
        // this.clearErrors(this.user);
        // this.showErrors(error);
      }
    );
  }
```